# Google Apps Script require login for webapp url / path

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, webapp2

I have an project in apps script for everyone and it has extra path

like

1. url/path1
2. url/path2

for that google apps script require an login to access the path

I have deploy web app as
Execute as me
who has access as anyone

so how can I remove that login for access that path

Comment: adding parameters in url after `/exec/`  is actually not accessible by anonymous user, that's why it is asking to login even you set it as `Anyone, even anonymous`.

Comment: but I wanted to give access without login what should I do?

Comment: Don't use path, but use query parameters